# RewriteRule in htaccess change url without content

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have one site with wordpress that have blog page.

So now for this page Url is somthing like **http://abc.com/blog**.

But i want to convert this url to **http://blog.abc.com**

I added code in .htaccess file but rewrite is not working. Rewrite mode is also on in apache.

Any one have idea how t o change this url ?

I want to test in my local wamp first, so please give suggestion with localhost too, if possible.

Code is that i tried

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc\.com/blog [NC] 
RewriteRule http://blog.abc [R=301,L]
```

Comment: If Jon's answer works for you then don't forget to mark that as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rule needs to look something like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ http://blog.abc.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

the `%{HTTP_HOST}` variable is *only* the hostname, and no path information is part of it (e.g. `/blog`). The `RewriteRule` takes at least 2 parameters:

```
RewriteRule <pattern to match against the URI> <if matched, rewrite/redirect to this URL> <flags>
```